# How do I get my 3 button controller on Wired Headphones to work/get enabled in Android 12?

Tags: buttons, headphones, volume

I have just acquired a **Lenovo M9 tablet** running **Android 12**.

It has a **3.5 mm** port for audio output.
All my **wired headphones** of various brands that have worked on all my previous Android devices, do not work with this tablet.

I can get Audio out but I **cannot use the volume+/-, PLAY/PAUSE hard buttons** on my headphones. They don't work at all.
Bluetooth headphones work OK.

My main reason for using wired headphones is so I can doze off and my ears don't have something sealing them, and I have a hand disability so find it hard enough to find my ear let alone trying to tap a sequence out. I can operate a controller though.

Lenovo couldn't help me but somewhere in the Android O/S **there must be an option to enable external device to take over controls using wired 'phones?**
Or, does it require the port to be of a particular type?

My workaround has been to use the Accessibility Shortcut to have a menu at side of screen to tap on, then I can use volume up/down but I still have to go to the notification shade to play/pause media. And that is still delayed with my awful dexterity.

I also searched for both the Headset Droid and Headset Controller Button apps which were both recommended on this forum 3 yrs ago but neither of those apps appear in Google's Play Store.
I do feel this could be remedied with correct drivers, but not a clue how to do that. I would be most grateful if someone could give me a fix to enable a hard controller. Or even a way to get play/pause/volume in an accessible but discrete floating button on-screen would help. I've tried loads of apps that just weren't that easy to use. Sorry, I can't remember which I used, they were all called volume control with no play or pause . Thanks :)

Comment: There are two different pin orders for headphones: CTIA and OMTP, see https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/15086/21257 and https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/accessories/headset/jack-headset-spec?hl=de

Answer (score 0):

Try using a settings database editor (e.g., [SetEdit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=by4a.setedit22) — you'll likely need to grant it additional permissions via ADB, per the instructions included within the app description on G Play market — and check your `Secure Table` for the following key/value pairing:
`media_button_receiver` : `ComponentInfo{com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro/com.mxtech.videoplayer.MediaButtonReceiver},0,1`
The included example value is for [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad), you may need to research the value you need for your specific use case.